# Is my constructor efficient?

Tags: java, constructor, this

For a programming assignment, I am asked to write

"a) A generic constructor that takes no values. This constructor lets you use the account with all the fields set to their default values.

b)  A constructor that takes five inputs. The first is a double and is the interest rate for the account, the second is a int as is the minimum balance for the account, the third is a double and is the overdraft fee for the account, the fourth is a double and is the ATM fee for the account, and the fifth is a double and is the bounced check fee for the account."

I am afraid that my code is redundant and inefficient. I was hoping someone would tell me what is unnecessary and/or if I am missing anything important. How can I create the generic constructor without manually initializing the fields? Also, I'm a bit worried that my second constructor does not initialize any fields besides the 5 listed as parameters.

```
public class BankAccount
{
  /*Balance of BankAccount*/
  private double balance = 0.00;

  /*Minimum balance allowed for BankAccount*/
  private int minimumBalance = 0;

  /*Interest rate of BankAccount*/
  private double interestRate = 0.00;

  /*Fee given everytime withdrawal is made via ATM*/
  private double ATMFee = 0.00;

  /*Amount deducted from balance if there is an overdraft*/
  private double overdraftFee = 0.00;

  /*Number of withdrawals allowed to be made before fee*/
  private int withdrawLimit = 0;

  /*Value to be deducted from balance if withdrawal limit is exceeded*/
  private double withdrawFee = 0.00;

  /*Keeps track of how many withdrawals owner has made*/
  private int withdrawCount = 0;

  /*Fee for bouncing a check*/
  private double bouncedCheckFee = 0.00;

  /*Stores interest earned*/
  private double interestEarned = 0.00;

  /*Whether or not overdraft fee has been charged*/
  private boolean overdraftFlag = false;

  /*Generic constructor takes no parameters and initializes field values to their default values*/
  public BankAccount()
  {
    this.balance = balance;
    this.minimumBalance = minimumBalance;
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
    this.ATMFee = ATMFee;
    this.overdraftFee = overdraftFee;
    this.withdrawLimit = withdrawLimit;
    this.withdrawFee = withdrawFee;
    this.withdrawCount = withdrawCount;
    this.bouncedCheckFee = bouncedCheckFee;
    this.interestEarned = interestEarned;
    this.overdraftFlag = overdraftFlag;
  }

  /*More specialized constructor takes 5 fields as parameters and initalizes them to their specified values*/
  public BankAccount(double interestRate, int minimumBalance, double overdraftFee, double ATMFee, double bouncedCheckFee)
  {
    this();
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
    this.minimumBalance = minimumBalance;
    this.overdraftFee = overdraftFee;
    this.ATMFee = ATMFee;
    this.bouncedCheckFee = bouncedCheckFee;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Okay I edited my code according to everyone's advice.

Here it is. Is it good now?

```
public class BankAccount
{
  /*Balance of BankAccount*/
  private double balance = 0.00;

  /*Minimum balance allowed for BankAccount*/
  private int minimumBalance = 0;

  /*Interest rate of BankAccount*/
  private double interestRate = 0.00;

  /*Fee given everytime withdrawal is made via ATM*/
  private double ATMFee = 0.00;

  /*Amount deducted from balance if there is an overdraft*/
  private double overdraftFee = 0.00;

  /*Number of withdrawals allowed to be made before fee*/
  private int withdrawLimit = 0;

  /*Value to be deducted from balance if withdrawal limit is exceeded*/
  private double withdrawFee = 0.00;

  /*Keeps track of how many withdrawals owner has made*/
  private int withdrawCount = 0;

  /*Fee for bouncing a check*/
  private double bouncedCheckFee = 0.00;

  /*Stores interest earned*/
  private double interestEarned = 0.00;

  /*Whether or not overdraft fee has been charged*/
  private boolean overdraftFlag = false;

  /*Generic constructor takes no parameters and initializes field values to their default values*/
  public BankAccount()
  {
  }

  /*More specialized constructor takes 5 fields as parameters and initalizes them to their specified values*/
  public BankAccount(double interestRate, int minimumBalance, double overdraftFee, double ATMFee, double bouncedCheckFee)
  {
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
    this.minimumBalance = minimumBalance;
    this.overdraftFee = overdraftFee;
    this.ATMFee = ATMFee;
    this.bouncedCheckFee = bouncedCheckFee;
  }
}
```

Comment: Every time someone uses floating-point for money, god kills 1.000000000003 kittens.

Comment: All the code in the first constructor doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Just doing what was assigned. I hate it just as much as you.

Comment: Titus, are you saying that I can simply write a constructor with no parameters or body and that the fields will be initialized?

Comment: Yes, and if you do that you won't need the `this()` call from the second constructor.

Comment: public BankAccount()
  {
  }

Comment: I would remove every field initialization in your code (expect the stuff from the constructor), because they do nothing else than assigning the [default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#h1), so they are superfluous.

Comment: @NolanHamilton Don't beat yourself up. Your code is fine. It is clear, everything has a purpose and it reads well.  The only comment I have :) (unless you are required to have them for course grade)  - get rid of the comments :). The names are self-explanatory. + what Tom said above.

Comment: I would get rid of the comments, but he specifically requested that we write them for every field, method, and constructor. A bit much if you ask me, but I want to make a good grade. Thanks again for your help. You're a very nice person

Comment: @NolanHamilton If you need to write these comments, then you should read a few things about [writing JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html) correctly (e.g for your constructors).

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor with no arguments, you re-assign the values of your fields, which is superflous. If you already give them a value in the declaration, you don't need to do it again in the constructor if you don't want it to have a different value.

Comment: Also, the `this()` call is redundant.

Comment: You mean the one in the second constructor? The other fields in BankAccount are initialized and not the just the five listed in the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

First off, your default `BankAccount()` constructor should be empty. It's just assigning the fields to themselves.

Second, please only include **mandatory** fields in your constructor. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854389/use-the-builder-pattern-to-create-mutable-objects/32854416#32854416) and either use setters after creation or use the Builder Pattern to build out your object using optional parameters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "  public BankAccount()
  {
  }"

Comment: mind checking the updated code? I edited my original post.

Comment: @NolanHamilton, yes much more concise. Good luck with your assignment!

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor repeat fields initialization that is already present in the field declarations. You can simply clean its body.

Another limit to your code is that when you have to create an object, you have to specify all the fields used in the constructor. You can avoid this, using the [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to get code more readable.

Now i translate what i said in code.

The code for the BankAccountOptions class:

```
public class BankAccountOptions {

    public static BankAccountOptions build() {
        return new BankAccountOptions();
    }

    public double aTMFee;

    public double balance;

    public double bouncedCheckFee;

    public double interestEarned;

    public float interestRate;

    public int minimumBalance;

    public double overdraftFee;

    public boolean overdraftFlag;

    public int withdrawCount;

    public double withdrawFee;

    public int withdrawLimit;

    public BankAccountOptions aTMFee(double value) {
        aTMFee = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions balance(double value) {
        balance = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions balance(int value) {
        minimumBalance = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions bouncedCheckFee(double value) {
        bouncedCheckFee = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions interestEarned(double value) {
        interestEarned = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions interestRate(float value) {
        interestRate = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions overdraftFee(double value) {
        overdraftFee = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions overdraftFlag(boolean value) {
        overdraftFlag = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions withdrawCount(int value) {
        withdrawCount = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions withdrawFee(double value) {
        withdrawFee = value;
        return this;
    }

    public BankAccountOptions withdrawLimit(int value) {
        withdrawLimit = value;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The class BankAccount

```
public class BankAccount {

/* Fee given everytime withdrawal is made via ATM */
private double ATMFee;

/* Balance of BankAccount */
private double balance;

/* Fee for bouncing a check */
private double bouncedCheckFee;

/* Stores interest earned */
private double interestEarned;

/* Interest rate of BankAccount */
private double interestRate;

/* Minimum balance allowed for BankAccount */
private int minimumBalance;

/* Amount deducted from balance if there is an overdraft */
private double overdraftFee;

/* Whether or not overdraft fee has been charged */
private boolean overdraftFlag;

/* Keeps track of how many withdrawals owner has made */
private int withdrawCount;

/* Value to be deducted from balance if withdrawal limit is exceeded */
private double withdrawFee;

/* Number of withdrawals allowed to be made before fee */
private int withdrawLimit;

/* Generic constructor takes no parameters and initializes field values to their default values */
public BankAccount() {
   this(BankAccountOptions.build());
}

BankAccount(BankAccountOptions options)
}

/* More specialized constructor takes 5 fields as parameters and initalizes them to their specified values */
public BankAccount(BankAccountOptions options) {
    balance = options.balance;
    minimumBalance = options.minimumBalance;
    interestRate = options.interestRate;
    ATMFee = options.aTMFee;
    overdraftFee = options.overdraftFee;
    withdrawLimit = options.withdrawLimit;
    withdrawFee = options.withdrawFee;
    withdrawCount = options.withdrawCount;
    bouncedCheckFee = options.bouncedCheckFee;
    interestEarned = options.interestEarned;
    overdraftFlag = options.overdraftFlag;
}
```

}

Now suppose you want to create a BankAccount object with default values. The code will be:

```
...
BankAccount account=new BankAccount();
...
```

If you want to create an account and modify only two attributes (i.e.  minimumBalance and withdrawLimit) you can write:

```
...
BankAccount account=new BankAccount(BankAccountOptions.build().minimumBalance(200).withdrawLimit(4));
...
```